# pandas different values on different dataframes

Tags: pandas

```
 df1: 
   **users**
   usr1
   usr2
   xyz2
   xyz3
   
 df2:

     GroupUsers  
0    usr1,usr2,usr3       
1    abc1,abc2,abc3        
2    def1,def2,def3
```

I'm trying to get differences of 2 dataframe. I need a column to df2.

I tried:
df2['other_users'] = df1['users']not in df2['GroupUsers']

Comment: Can you add expected output? In sample data is no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda function with `split` and `join`:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(y for y in df1['users'] if y not in x.split(','))
df2['other_users'] =  df2['GroupUsers'].apply(f)
print (df2)
       GroupUsers                    other_users
0  usr1,usr2,usr3                 xyz1,xyz2,xyz3
1  abc1,abc2,abc3  usr1,usr2,usr3,xyz1,xyz2,xyz3
2  def1,def2,def3  usr1,usr2,usr3,xyz1,xyz2,xyz3
```

Comment: .you are the best :) Thank you

Comment: one more thing if you do not mind. This works for df1 and df2. If I have multiple files that includes 2 dataframes like df1 and df2, is it possible to apply same logic at the same time? @jezrael

Comment: @dvlp - Can you explian more? There is a lot of pairs `df1, df2` from files ? How you can distingush if files are pairs?

Comment: For example there are different systems. Each system has Users and Group users dataframes. Sorry if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks, I just  tried to do it for all systems at the same time. Used all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")) and created dataframes. But at last part I stucked.

Comment: @dvlp - Unfortunately not sure if understan what mean `system`? Do you think different operation systems? If same operation system, `all_files` generate all files, how is possible get pairs `df1, df2` if many files?

Comment: Allright, thanks for your help, maybe I will ask it in another question with details.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in df2['GroupUsers'] lists or strings?
Either way you can do it by setting up a blank column, then iterating through the dataframe row by row.

If the values in df2['GroupUsers'] are lists:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Users':['user1','user2','user3','xyz1','xyz2','xyz3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GroupUsers':[['user1','user4','user5'],['abc1','abc2','abc3'],['xyz1','sas2','sas3']]})

df2['other_users'] = ""
for row_number, row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.at[row_number, 'other_users'] = [item for item in row['GroupUsers'] if item not in list(df1['Users'])]
```

If the values in df2['GroupUsers'] are strings, it's the same process but split the list:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Users':['user1','user2','user3','xyz1','xyz2','xyz3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GroupUsers':['user1,user4,user5','abc1,abc2,abc3','xyz1,sas2,sas3']})

df2['other_users'] = ""
for row_number, row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.at[row_number, 'other_users'] = [item for item in row['GroupUsers'].split(',') if item not in list(df1['Users'])]
```

Either way, output of the above is:

```
display(df2)
    GroupUsers          other_users
0   user1,user4,user5   [user4, user5]
1   abc1,abc2,abc3      [abc1, abc2, abc3]
2   xyz1,sas2,sas3      [sas2, sas3]
```

Remember to use dataframe.at[] instead of dataframe.loc[] otherwise pandas will get confused about the concept of putting a list in a single cell.